# Data-bind style not working with if else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm trying to change the background of a div depending from the value I'm getting from the js file.

So if the value is different from 0 I would like to have one background and if its 0 I want another background.

This is the markup I'm trying with:

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: skills">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div data-bind="attr: { id: Id }, style: { background: Outstanding != '0' ? 'none repeat scroll 0 0 #B33A3A;' : 'none repeat scroll 0 0 #396eac;' }">
                <span data-bind="text: Name" style="color: #ffffff;"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span data-bind="visible: Outstanding != '0', text: Outstanding + ' Needed'" style="color: #365474"></span><br/> 
                <span data-bind="text: Employees" style="color: #365474"></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Do you guys see anything not correct here?

PS. Using the Chrome addon Knockoutjs context debugger I was able to see that the actual value of `Outstanding` is 0:

[image: debugger]

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary semicolon (;) at the end of the background value.
Change the line to be:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: Id }, style: { background: Outstanding != '0' ? 'none repeat scroll 0 0 #B33A3A' : 'none repeat scroll 0 0 #396eac' }">
```

That should fix it.

See example below:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    
    function MyVM() {
        var self = this;
        self.skills = ko.observableArray([
            { Id: 1, Outstanding: '0', Name: 'Foo', Employees: 'Person A' },
            { Id: 2, Outstanding: '1', Name: 'Bar', Employees: 'Person B' }
        ]);
        
        
    }
    
    ko.applyBindings(new MyVM(), document.body);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: skills">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div data-bind="attr: { id: Id }, style: { background : Outstanding !== '0' ?  'none repeat scroll 0 0 #B33A3A' : 'none repeat scroll 0 0 #396eac' }">
                    <span data-bind="text: Name" style="color: #ffffff;"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span data-bind="visible: Outstanding != '0', text: Outstanding + ' Needed'" style="color: #365474"></span><br/> 
                    <span data-bind="text: Employees" style="color: #365474"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Might want to be careful on that Outstanding comparison if the model is not actually a string.  I don't know your data structure but just in case it is a number, it might be problematic.  Perhaps massage it to a boolean...

Comment: using != as opposed to !== will match numeric 0 and the '0' character